# Will the system crash when I use Log.d in real mobile in android?

Tags: android

Will the android mobile crash when I install an app with following code in real mobile? Thanks!

```
Log.d("Mytag", "Test code");
```

Comment: y don't u try before asking here

Comment: Do you have a special reason in mind? The logging itself runs everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never be an issue. It will run perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no reason the app should stop working.
Moreover, if you use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), you could add the following in your proguard.cfg to remove the verbose and debug statements from your release APK.

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no issue also import

```
import android.util.Log;
```